# Unity I need a guide to make rts game move building

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Hello I’m just newbie of making a rts game need a little guide or advise
A little logic is enough

Right now i can make the building build itself but i want the building itself that have custom interior inside can move freely and still have interior inside

First time use stackoverflow btw

I tried to make a old school rts game we have temptilemap maintilemap to build building and in building have their own tilemap to customize interior

I want to find the way to collect interior inside with the building

Like barn1 have craftingtable,stove
And when i move barn1 craftingtable,stove would be the same as inside barn1

Like stardew valley barn that we can custom interior furniture and move building to anyway and interior inside still the same

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.